# Upgrading to scipy 1.7 in Anaconda?

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I currently have scipy 1.6.3 in my Conda installation, but I need scipy 1.7 because it has additional, important functions. I tried a few codes in the anaconda prompt, such as:

> conda update --all

and also

> conda install scipy

However, when I then typed "conda list" command to see what version of scipy installed, it remained at 1.6.3 (not the latest version, which is 1.7).

do you know what I could be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge scipy
```

Version 1.7: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scipy

Version 1.6: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/scipy

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for asking this! I just ran into the same problem. The command `conda install scipy=1.7.0 --yes` is not enough. `conda install -c conda-forge scipy=1.7.0 --yes` is what worked for me. It took some time before it updated.

IMPORTANT EDIT: Upgrading to SciPy 1.7.0 for me in anaconda made SciPy unusable to me. Importing SciPy to check the version would give me the following error:
`FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\Computer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\.libs\libbanded5x.X7D476RWJKO3TRH4FXIEB4YEAKNOYBT4.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.`

I reverted back to SciPy 1.6.2 by using `conda update --all --yes` (conda apparently removes/downgrades incompatible package versions with this command even if they're the latest). SciPy is once again usable to me.

I don't mind Scipy being at 1.6.2 for me now. I'll just wait until Anaconda/conda can catch up.

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I try :

```
STAT-Spip-~/Unix/Python/Tests  conda create -n TEST -c conda-forge scipy
STAT-Spip-~/Unix/Python/Tests  conda activate TEST
TEST-Spip-~/Unix/Python/Tests  python
Python 3.9.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 11 2021, 03:36:15)
[Clang 11.1.0 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
>>> dir(scipy)
['test']
>>>
>>> dir(scipy.test)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'module_name']
```

Seems that scipy 1.7 on conda-forge is a bit strange :-((

Same problem with osx-64 channel

Olivier